# Trigger to fill attribute table

Tags: postgresql, sql

how to trigger this function on the update for each row through pgadmin? (I am new to coding)

```
aggregate(
 layer:= 'layer_name',
 aggregate:='concatenate',
 expression:=field_name,
 concatenator:=', ',
 filter:=contains($geometry, geometry(@parent))
 )
```

Comment: This is not SQL code. It will not work outside of QGIS because it uses QGIS functions such as `aggregate()` and `$geometry`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a database trigger you need to write it in PL/pgSQL or another language supported on your database server.

If what you want to achieve is to concatenate all field_value values when the geometry is contained in another geometry your trigger will need to use a SQL `select ... group by...` statement.

An introduction to Postgres triggers is at https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-triggers/creating-first-trigger-postgresql/ .

I would start by writing the SQL statement you want on the database, and when you have a working statement you can then turn it into a trigger.